# Change text of button with tkinter with button stored in panda data frame

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I recently discovered Tkinter and wanted to try to build a graphical interface to keep track of stock of some items.

I have a panda table holding the information for each product: Name, In Stock (quantity currently available), Coming (quantity on its way). Each product has its own button, displaying the name of the product, the quantity in stock and the quantity underway.

When clicking on a combination of product + quantity + action, a function has to be called that will update the text displayed for each product button. **My problem is that I can't seem to access correctly the text of the button to update it.**
In order to have one generic function to update the text of the button for a product, I saved the buttons in the pandas data frame holding my products in a column called `Button`. I wanted to access the button based on the product button clicked `df_product.loc[df_product["Name"] == df_changes.iloc[0, 0], "Button"]`, and then update the text of the button by changing its `['text']`. 
This however doesn't work, as the element stored in the `Button` column is of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, holding the value of `.!frame.!button2` and not `<class 'tkinter.Button'>`.

My code is as follow:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()

# Create source df
df_product = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Juice', 'Cereal', 'Can'], 'In Stock': [0, 0, 0], 'Coming': [0, 0, 0], 'Button': [0, 0, 0]})

# Create & Configure root
root.geometry('720x480')

Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

# Empty data frame to store the changes
df_changes = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['-1'], 'Quantity': ['-1'], 'Action': ['-1']})


# Create functions
def set_name(name_product):
    df_changes.iloc[0, 0] = name_product
    if name_product == '-1':
        recall_product['text'] = 'Make Product Selection'
    else:
        recall_product['text'] = 'Product selected'+'\n'+df_changes.iloc[0, 0]
    check_action()


def set_quantity(amount):
    df_changes.iloc[0, 1] = amount
    if amount == '-1':
        recall_quantity['text'] = 'Make Quantity Selection'
    else:
        recall_quantity['text'] = 'Quantity:'+'\n'+str(df_changes.iloc[0, 1])
    check_action()


def set_action(action):
    df_changes.iloc[0, 2] = action
    if action == '-1':
        recall_action['text'] = 'Make Action Selection'
    else:
        recall_action['text'] = 'Action selected'+'\n'+df_changes.iloc[0, 2]
    check_action()


def check_action():
    # Verify if the 3 elements (Product, Quantity adn Action) have been selected
    if df_changes.iloc[0, 0] != '-1' and df_changes.iloc[0, 1] != '-1' and df_changes.iloc[0, 2] != '-1':
        # If yes, verify which action needs to occure
        if df_changes.iloc[0, 2] == 'In Stock':
            # Update the quantity In Stock for the product selected
            df_product.loc[df_product["Name"] == df_changes.iloc[0, 0], "In Stock"] += int(df_changes.iloc[0, 1])
            # Update the text of the button to show the new quantity In Stock
            df_product.loc[df_product["Name"] == df_changes.iloc[0, 0], "Button"]['text'] = str(df_changes.iloc[0, 0])+'\n\n'+str(int(df_product.loc[df_product["Name"] == df_changes.iloc[0, 0], "In Stock"]))+'\n\n+'+str(int(df_product.loc[df_product["Name"] == df_changes.iloc[0, 0], "Coming"]))
        # Reset the table holding the buttons pressed
        set_name('-1')
        set_quantity('-1')
        set_action('-1')

# Create & Configure frame
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame_pad = Frame(frame)
frame_pad.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame_action = Frame(frame)
frame_action.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

frame_recall = Frame(frame)
frame_recall.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

# Create Product Button
df_product['Button'].iloc[0] = Button(frame, text=str(df_product['Name'][0])+'\n\n'+str(df_product['In Stock'][0])+'\n\n+'+str(df_product['Coming'][0]), font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_name(str(df_product['Name'][0])))
df_product['Button'].iloc[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
df_product['Button'].iloc[1] = Button(frame, text=str(df_product['Name'][1])+'\n\n'+str(df_product['In Stock'][1])+'\n\n+'+str(df_product['Coming'][1]), font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_name(str(df_product['Name'][1])))
df_product['Button'].iloc[1].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
df_product['Button'].iloc[2] = Button(frame, text=str(df_product['Name'][2])+'\n\n'+str(df_product['In Stock'][2])+'\n\n+'+str(df_product['Coming'][2]), font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_name(str(df_product['Name'][2])))
df_product['Button'].iloc[2].grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)

# Quantity buttons
textQ = Label(frame_pad, text='Quantity', font=('Courrier', 25))
textQ.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)

btn_nb0 = Button(frame_pad, text=0, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(0))
btn_nb0.grid(row=int(0/5)+1, column=0 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb1 = Button(frame_pad, text=1, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(1))
btn_nb1.grid(row=int(1/5)+1, column=1 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb2 = Button(frame_pad, text=2, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(2))
btn_nb2.grid(row=int(2/5)+1, column=2 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb3 = Button(frame_pad, text=3, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(3))
btn_nb3.grid(row=int(3/5)+1, column=3 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb4 = Button(frame_pad, text=4, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(4))
btn_nb4.grid(row=int(4/5)+1, column=4 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb5 = Button(frame_pad, text=5, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(5))
btn_nb5.grid(row=int(5/5)+1, column=5 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb6 = Button(frame_pad, text=6, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(6))
btn_nb6.grid(row=int(6/5)+1, column=6 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb7 = Button(frame_pad, text=7, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(7))
btn_nb7.grid(row=int(7/5)+1, column=7 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb8 = Button(frame_pad, text=8, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(8))
btn_nb8.grid(row=int(8/5)+1, column=8 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)
btn_nb9 = Button(frame_pad, text=9, font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_quantity(9))
btn_nb9.grid(row=int(9/5)+1, column=9 % 5, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=2, pady=5)

# Action buttons
btn1 = Button(frame_action, text='In Stock', font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_action(btn1['text']))
btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
btn2 = Button(frame_action, text='Ordered', font=('Courrier', 25), command=lambda: set_action(btn2['text']))
btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)

# Recall Labels, for the user to know what has been pressed
recall_product = Label(frame_recall, text=df_changes.iloc[0, 0], font=('Courrier', 15))
recall_product.pack()
recall_quantity = Label(frame_recall, text=df_changes.iloc[0, 1], font=('Courrier', 15))
recall_quantity.pack()
recall_action = Label(frame_recall, text=df_changes.iloc[0, 2], font=('Courrier', 15))
recall_action.pack()

# Make all the elements adjust correctly to resizing
for x in range(1):
  Grid.columnconfigure(frame_pad, x, weight=1)
for y in range(3):
  Grid.rowconfigure(frame_pad, y, weight=1)

for x in range(1):
  Grid.columnconfigure(frame_action, x, weight=1)
for y in range(2):
  Grid.rowconfigure(frame_action, y, weight=1)

Grid.columnconfigure(frame_recall, 0, weight=1)
for y in range(1):
  Grid.rowconfigure(frame_recall, y, weight=1)

for x in range(4):
  Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
for y in range(4):
  Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

frame_pad.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
frame_action.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
frame_recall.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W, padx=5, pady=5)

# Display window
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your sample and it is quite unclear what you are trying to do. But my suggestion is to have you gui only reads and update data from your `Dataframe`. It could be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

df_product = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Juice', 'Cereal', 'Can'], 'In Stock': [0, 0, 0], 'Coming': [0, 0, 0], 'Button': [0, 0, 0]})

root = tk.Tk()
data = {}

def selection(txt, widget):
    for v in data.values():
        v[-1].config(relief="raised",bg="SystemButtonFace")
    widget.config(relief="sunken",bg="red")
    item.set(txt)

def set_amount():
    result = data.get(item.get())
    if result:
        to_change = result[0] if inventory.get()=="In Stock" else result[1]
        to_change.config(text=amount.get())

for row, x in enumerate(df_product.itertuples()):
    button = tk.Button(root,text=x[1],width=10)
    button.config(command=lambda b=button, x=x[1]: selection(x,b))
    button.grid(row=row, column=0)
    data[x[1]] = []
    for col, txt in enumerate(x[2:-1],1):
        label = tk.Label(root,text=txt,width=10)
        label.grid(row=row, column=col)
        data[x[1]].append(label)
    data[x[1]].append(button)

tk.Label(root,text="Item selected:",width=10).grid(row=0,column=3)

item = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root,textvariable=item,width=10).grid(row=0,column=4)

inventory = ttk.Combobox(root,values=("In Stock","Coming"),state="readonly",width=10)
inventory.grid(row=1,column=3)
inventory.current(0)

amount = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, width=3,state="readonly")
amount.grid(row=1,column=4)

submit = tk.Button(root,text="Submit change",command=set_amount)
submit.grid(row=2,column=3,columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that this does not have the mechanism to write back to the `Dataframe` but should be easy enough to implement.